# Developing an Android App that interfaces with a website- Help!

Tags: android

Hey,
So I'm trying to develop an App that will take the users ID and Password and then log onto a site in the background and tranfer the users contacts from the phone to the site. I'm doing this for my final year project in college. I'm new to this and have been completely lost since developing the GUI. Is there a particular library I should look at or a name for what I am trying to do that I could look for tutorials on? Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the website you are connecting to for the upload under your own control?  If so, it makes it much easier as you can debug both ends of the connection.

For the Android side, I'd use the `HttpClient` to perform an `HttpPost` of the required data.  Look for Java tutorials that cover uploads using these methods.  Bear in mind that the Android libraries do use v4.x of the `HttpClient`, but they are not the very latest versions, so make sure you develop against the `android.jar` versions and not the `httpclient-4.1-alpha2.jar` ones.

For the web side you will want either a `jsp` or `php` solution, where you parse the incoming POST request and save the data (I assume to a database).  Again, look for tutorials that cover these points.  Good luck.

Comment: Hey, the web site isn't under my control. I'd planned on using the web sites "add contact page" to repeatedly insert the contacts from the phone. Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: I think so yes. You will need to mimic the behaviour of a web browser performing POST requests.  You can get an idea of the data you need to submit by using something like the `Live Http Headers` extension for FireFox, or using the `Charles Proxy` to monitor form submissions in your browser.  Then submit data in the same manner using the `HttpClient`.

Comment: Great thanks, I'm installing that ad on now. This is all pretty new to me, but I'm definately alot happier now knowing where to look and having a general idea of the approach I need to take. You've been a great help. I'll burry myself in it for the weekend and hopefully it all goes well.

Comment: With Live HTTP HEaders, should I be looking under the Headers or Generator Tab. This is what is generated under the Generator tab when I log in: POST /go/mymeteor-login-manager username=086*******&userpass=****&x=22&y=12&returnTo=%2F but I'm still unsure of how to code this

Comment: @Colm Shannon yeah that looks like a regular POST request form submission.  Just look up some tutorials on how to perform them in Java.

Comment: there seems to be some attributes in the posts (i.e. in the example above the x and y attributes) that vary with each post. I've come across several of these, and am wondering if they can be ignored, or if they need to be pulled from somewhere?

Comment: @Colm Shannon The `x` and `y` values are normally because the `<input...>` is of `type=image`.  The values represent the position on the image that was clicked by the user.  Unless the server is changing its behaviour based on where on the image is clicked, then you could either hard code them to `0` or leave them out completely.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just post a HTTP request with the login information and than parse the result with the user data. The response can be anything from csv, xml to json. Just look for tutorials about http requests/response with android and you should find anything you need.

Comment: great thanks alot, I'll look into it 2day. Its a relief just to know it will be possible :-D